# Help: Text Mining + Classification - From customer comments to predicted solution

Tags: text-mining

I have a data set that consists of the information generated by a service call for a home appliance.

The data set consists of a column with the sentence of the customer's complaint and a corresponding column of the part that the service technician replaced.

I am new to machine learning algorithms and I was wondering if anyone could help me get started using a text mining algorithm that will classify the customer's comments into one of the 56 parts that should be replaced.

In short, I want to use this data set as a training set in order to predict the repair needed based on the customer's comment.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that sounds for me as an instance of a text classification problem. As far as I understand, the classes in your scenario represent parts that can/sould be replaced, correct? If yes, you first should figure out, which features are discriminative enough in order to distinguish among the 56 possible classes. In machine learning terms, this process is called feature selection/extraction and can be automated (to some degree).

Note, that before you can apply feature selection/extraction you should apply an appropriate preprocessing on your data. Afterwards you can  generate feature vectors and feed your classifier (e.g. $k$-NN, MaxEnt, SVM, Naive Bayes, etc.). Using a classifier, however, requires a training set, which should be representative enough. So i think you should start here first...

Comment: For pre-processing, should I be removing some of the stop words or words that add no value to the prediction?  

Since I have the column consisting of each sentence, and the corresponding column of the repair, is there any classification algorithm that you would recommend?

Comment: Removing stopwords is a typical task, when one wants to classify the content, so I believe that is corresponds also to your problem. Regarding the classifier, I would recommend a simple $k$-NN, Naive Bayes or a decision tree. Note that your training data should be labeld appropriate. Each comment forms a class, not each sentence. If you say that a comment can have more than one corresponding classes than you need to apply multi-label classification. In SciKit there is the "OneVsRestClassifier" that can handle this sort of problem: 

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html